# Migrate website to a new server while preserving database state

Tags: web-applications, deployment, server, migration, database-migration

We're about to move our website to a new server and I'm trying to come up with a sound migration plan.

Our current setup consists of a single server (A) with a website running under Apache and a local MySQL database on the same server.

Since all session data is stored in the database, we need to somehow synchronize it with the database in the new server (B) to prevent loss of data (user sessions, application state, etc) during the migration period when both the new and the old website will be running at the same time until the DNS changes fully propagate. My current plan is as follows:

1. Set up a copy of the production server's (A) database in the new server (B).
2. Point the web application in the old server (A) to the database in the new server (B).
3. Set up the web application at the new server (B) and point it to the database which is now running locally on server B. Both web application instances (the one at the current server A and the one at the new server B) are now using the database on server B simultaneously.
4. Make the website on server B accessible to the public and redirect the current website domain to point to the new web application instance at server B.
5. Wait for the DNS record changes to propagate and shut down server A once the website traffic moves to the new server.

Is this strategy good? What would be the typical procedure when migrating the website to a new server in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Mysql Clustering, I used galera for a while; you can try setting up 2 Primary MySQL servers (both can write and read) and you can decide the rest as you move on.